# Ask Stack Overflow for Atom Editor

Tags: app

## Ask Stack Overflow for Atom

Quickly get answers and code samples from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) directly in Atom editor.

Package: https://atom.io/packages/ask-stack

GitHub: https://github.com/Chris911/Ask-Stack-Atom

[image: Preview]

### Features

- Insert or copy code samples with the click of a button
- Easily browse between questions and answers
- Sort by relevance or votes
- Access to the number of votes, tags, accepted answer and more

### Usage

Toggle the Ask Stack Overlow form using `CTRL + ALT + A` or by typing `Ask Stack` in the command bar.

### Installation

[Package homepage](https://atom.io/packages/ask-stack)

**Install from the command line:** 
`$ apm install ask-stack`

### Contributing

1. Fork it
2. Create your feature branch (`git checkout -b my-new-feature`)
3. Commit your changes (`git commit -am 'Add some feature'`)
4. Push to the branch (`git push origin my-new-feature`)
5. Create new Pull Request

Comment: Wow! I don't use Atom, but this almost makes me want to ;)

Comment: Stack Overflow Driven Development

Comment: It would be very cool if you could ask in more stack exchange sites (like tex.stackexchange.com).